# How can locality-sensitive hashing (LSH) be used for clustering / grouping similar images?

Tags: java, image-processing

I want to search an image from a big amount of images by using `LSH` in Java language . But I am new to this, can you tell me please, how to do such staff for example what should I need to download and give me a simple working example. Thanks!

Comment: There's no magic `Lsh.do()` function, no simple solution. That is because the problem domain is inherently hard. Why do you even want LSH?

Comment: I just want find how to use, I am using OpenCV and want to search an image in much big amount of images, I saw someone says that they can do it with OpenCV SIFT algorithm+LSH it is mush fast. Now I Just want to know how to use LSH with OpenCV?